# The completion of metric spaces with bounded sequences instead of Cauchy sequences

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, terminology, complete-spaces

Out of idle curiosity, I was mulling the idea of the completion of a metric space.

In a nutshell, one starts with a metric space $(M, d)$, defines an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set of Cauchy sequences by $(x_n) \sim (y_n)$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n) = 0$. We let $\overline{M}$ be the set of equivalence classes, and define $\overline{d}$, a metric on $\overline{M}$, by
$$\overline{d}((x_n), (y_n)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n).$$
Naturally, one needs to prove that the above limit exists, and the metric is well-defined, but this all works out. We get the unique complete metric space, up to isometry, containing $M$ as a dense subspace.

Now, what if, instead of making an equivalence relation on Cauchy sequences, we instead use bounded sequences? For bounded sequences $(x_n), (y_n)$ in $M$, we say $(x_n) \sim (y_n)$ if and only if $\operatorname*{limsup}_{n\to \infty} d(x_n, y_n) \to 0$. We then define $\widetilde{M}$ to be the set of equivalence classes, and let
$$\widetilde{d}((x_n), (y_n)) = \operatorname*{limsup}_{n \to \infty} d(x_n, y_n).$$
It's not difficult to see $\widetilde{d}$ is a well-defined metric on $\widetilde{M}$.

**Question:** Has this construction been studied before? Does it, or something equivalent to it, have a name? Where could I find more information about it?

Some observations:

1. $\widetilde{M}$ contains $\overline{M}$ as a (complete) subspace.
2. $\widetilde{M}$ is itself complete.
3. If $X$ is a normed linear space, then $\widetilde{X}$ is a linear space as well: the sequence space $\ell^\infty(X)$, quotiented by the closed subspace of null-convergent sequences of $X$. If $d$ is the metric derived from the norm $\|\cdot\|_X$, then the metric $\widetilde{d}$ is derived from the quotient norm
   $$\|(x_n)\|_{\widetilde{X}} = \operatorname*{limsup}_{n \to \infty} \|x_n\|_X.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is wildly more complicated than the Cauchy completion. Here is what it looks like for $M = \mathbb{R}$; first, the vector space of bounded sequences $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ can be identified with the commutative [$C^{\ast}$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) of continuous functions $\beta \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\beta \mathbb{N}$ is the [Stone-Cech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of $\mathbb{N}$, which can be identified with the space of [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter#Ultrafilter_on_the_power_set_of_a_set) on $\mathbb{N}$. $\widetilde{ \mathbb{R} }$ is obtained by quotienting by the subspace of sequences converging to $0$, which can be identified with the closed ideal of functions on $\beta \mathbb{N}$ vanishing on the complement $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$.

The quotient by this closed ideal then produces another $C^{\ast}$-algebra, which is the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of continuous functions on $\beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, the space of non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$. This is a very complicated space. Somewhat more explicitly, the bijection from $\widetilde{\mathbb{R}}$ to this algebra of continuous functions sends a bounded sequence to the function which sends a non-principal ultrafilter to the [ultralimit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit#Limit_of_a_sequence_of_points_with_respect_to_an_Ultrafilter) of the sequence with respect to the ultrafilter. (Maybe this continues to be a bijection for more general $M$, at least if $M$ is complete, but I don't know.)

Comment: Wow! Thank you. +1. I do feel I should point out, it's not *exactly* an answer to my question, but I really do appreciate you sharing this. Given how quickly you managed to write this answer, I'm guessing you've thought about something similar to this previously? Or are you really that quick? :)

Comment: @Theo: the key to solving problems is just to have seen similar problems before. The first bit of this argument is a special case of a more general identification between the $C^{\ast}$-algebra $C_b(X, \mathbb{R})$ of bounded continuous functions on a topological space $X$ and the $C^{\ast}$-algebra $C(\beta X, \mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions on the Stone-Cech compactification. This can be used to construct the Stone-Cech compactification and is part of the folklore around the commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem. I have also thought specifically about $\beta \mathbb{N}$ for a few reasons.

Comment: I am not confident about the details but it should still be true that if $M$ is a complete metric space then we can identify bounded sequences $\mathbb{N} \to M$ with continuous functions $\beta \mathbb{N} \to M$, by taking ultralimits. I am less sure about what happens after the quotient.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed you must have thought about something similar. I did cover the Stone-Cech compactification many years ago in my honours year (but it wasn't using ultrafilters; I honestly can't recall the construction we used), and it did come to mind when examining this construction. I discarded those thoughts when I realised that $\widetilde{M}$ was certainly not compact, generally speaking.

Comment: @TheoBendit first of all, I am sorry for post this comment in a place that does not belong to. Two years ago, you were so nice with me in another post. So I am asking you for any help in this.... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4797950/what-hypothesis-can-i-assum-in-order-to-obtain-infinity-solutions-for-this-probl  Again sorry, for post here, I do not have your contact to find you in other way... I would like to meet you, or at least know who you are. I can tell you first who I am.

Comment: @Silvinha Sorry, PDEs are not really in my wheelhouse.

Comment: @TheoBendit, oh ok. Thanks for your attention. S2